# SASS variables and 'composes': $grey-darker not found

Tags: sass, bulma

I try to use Bulma in my webpack-based project and I get an error on using a style:

**styles.scss:**

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import '~bulma/sass/base/_all.sass';

.title {
  composes: title is-3 from 'bulma/sass/elements/title.sass';
}
```

**webpack.js:**

```
            {
                test : /\.scss$/,
                use : [ {
                    loader : "style-loader",
                }, {
                    loader : "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
                    options : {
                        camelCase : true,
                        namedExport : true,
                        modules : true,
                        importLoaders : 2
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                }]
            }
```

And the error is

```
   Undefined variable: "$grey-darker".
   in C:\Users\XXXX\bulma-test\src\main\frontend\node_modules\bulma\sass\elements\title.sass (line 1, column 15)
```

The file exists and the requested variable is defined within

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
```

If I don't import the variables on my own and simple compose from bulma

```
  composes: title is-3 from 'bulma';
```

and not from the file title.sass then everything works fine - expect that I import the entire bulma style what I try to avoid with my attempts of composing from title.

The Bulma files can be found here: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma. And these are my dependencies:

```
    "bulma": "^0.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
```

Has anyone an idea why this variable is unkown?

Thx, Stephan

Comment: This may be helpful? https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/190